# Using ScalaTest with SBT android-sdk-plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

I'm trying to use SBT with android-sdk-plugin and ScalaTest, but have no success.

I could run `test` command in SBT console, but it didn't find any ScalaTest test suite in my `src/test/scala` folder.

I got the following output from SBT, which seems didn't run any ScalaTest test suite at all.

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /home/brianhsu/AndroidProject/FindLost/target/android-bin/classes...
[info] Packaging /home/brianhsu/AndroidProject/FindLost/target/android-bin/classes.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /home/brianhsu/AndroidProject/FindLost/target/scala-2.10/findlost_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Run completed in 44 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] No tests to run for test:test
```

The following is how I create the project:

1. Using `android create project -g` to create an Android project with gradle layout.
2. Add `addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.2.11")` to `project/plugins.sbt` to include android-sdk-plugin to my project.
3. Add ScalaTest to my `libraryDependencies` setting in build.sbt, which makes the build file looks like the following:

   ```
   import android.Keys._

   android.Plugin.androidBuild

   name := "FindLost"

   scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

   organization := "org.bone.findlost"

   libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"

   platformTarget in Android := "android-19"

   run <<= run in Android

   install <<= install in Android
   ```
4. Add a ScalaTest test case to `src/test/scala`, which contains example test suite from [QuickStart](http://www.scalatest.org/quick_start) page of ScalaTest.

Answer (score 2):

Place your tests in `src/androidTest/scala`

The android-sdk-plugin uses `androidTest` for both Android instrumentation tests as well as regular tests.

See [Ordinary scalatests not found from src/test #45](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/45) for a discussion on this topic. Note, that since that discussion the plugin changed directory has changed to the path I listed.

Comment: How is it that it is not documented anywhere but here, that you should put the tests under an androidTest folder when using the android-sdk-plugin!?